# Is there a way to force use of one particular DNS server among multiple listed?

Tags: networking, network-manager, 15.04, dnsmasq

Before pushing new configuration changes on our DNS servers, I like to test and verify on a 'test' server before applying the changes on our 'production' servers.

So this is my deck network config :

[image]

.57 is my 'test' server, .22 and .44 are our 'production' servers; is there a way to force my deck to force doing DNS query on .57 instead of .22 and .44?

... maybe `--all-servers` or `--strict-order` options? I'm not sure how to apply those to the NetworkManager dnsmasq subprocess...

++ **EDIT** ++

I forgot to mention that .57 is running locally via VirtualBox, so I need multiple DNS defined in order to respond (in case I forgot to start it or is not working)

Comment: ... I made all kind of tests with dnsmasq options, to no avail! Maybe my thinking of this is just flawed!

Answer (score 1):

`nslookup` allows specifying dns server . you can use that to test queries, like so `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` ,replace 8.8.8.8 with your desired server. `Dig` command offers same functionality. More info in `man nslookup` and `man dig`

Comment: That is totally accurate, but it doesn't help testing access through SSH or HTTPS... I'm starting to think my question isn't as thoroughly developed as it should!

Answer (score 1):

Generally the primary server is used first. That's why it is called the primary server. So in your case '.57' is used which is what you want. Only if it does not respond the secondary server is contacted. If that one does not respond too the teriary server is contacted. If none of them responds you'll get an error about resolving.

And there's a 100% reliable solution to your problem too: In your networkmanager specify the '.57' server only, not the other ones, and then you'll know for sure that's the only one contacted.

Comment: I totally agree, but since I modify it constantly and have to restart it a lot, I guess `dnsmasq` keeps flagging it as _unreliable_ compared to the other 2! And since .57 is running locally via **VirtualBox** - another thing I forgot to mention in my question! - I need other servers defined to respond to queries in case it's not started or plain broken

Comment: Why do you have dnsmasq any way? I know: it is standard on Ubuntu... But dnsmasq acts as a local DNS server itself, so now you've to make it to forward to one of your other DNS servers. What I recommend you to do is disabling dnsmasq. Edit the file: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and add a # in front of the line that reads dns=dnsmasq then restart. Now go to the networkmanager select the ipv4 settings tab and there add the '.57' server as your DNS server.

Comment: You're telling me to only have .57 as my DNS server? If **VirtualBox** ain't working, I would loose DNS resolution all together...

Comment: Since your question was is there a way to force my deck to force doing DNS query on .57 instead of .22 and .44?', yes, I tell you how to use that particular server. If you loose DNS resolution then you'll at least what's wrong. Remember You should not do this in a production environment, but only on the test server.

Comment: After much consideration and thinking, I think my logic about this is just wrong : having a 'test' server alongside 'production' servers is not ideal, but you gave me some ideas. I think I'll disable `nm-dnsmasq` form my deck, install `bind9` locally and define .22 and .44 as forwarders; that way I can test new entries locally before pushing them in production and if I loose DNS function all-together I'll know it right away... what do you think?

Comment: That sounds good to me. Make sure you set the correct 'forward' directive or else bind9 will forward always and not doing resolving any itself. If you believe my original answer was useful for then please accept it by clicking the grey checkmark on the left side so it turns to green, also other users will know your question is solved.